# mysql connect timeout

Tags: c++, mysql

I need to set the timeout for mysql_real_connect. The problem is when a server is not running  Timeout is rediculusly long, and this "freezes" my application. I tried using MYSQL_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT but still it is taking time to return from mysql_real_connect.

Sample code:

```
MYSQL mysql;
unsigned int conn_timeout=1;

mysql_init(&mysql);
mysql_options(&mysql, MYSQL_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, &conn_timeout);

if(mysql_real_connect(&mysql, "localhost","root", "root", NULL, 3306, NULL,0) == FALSE)
{  
    cout<<"Connection Failed" ;       
    return 1;
}    
cout<<"Connection Success";
```

If server is not running, it is taking 20 seconds to return from mysql_real_connect.

Is there any way to set timeout for mysql_real_connect so that it will return after the specified timeout?
Please help.

Comment: you sure you using `MYSQL_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT` correctly, because that should be the way to go? Consider pasting some code. Anyway, I recommend reading man http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-options.html it may clear things up

Comment: Adding an updated link to mysql_options 8.0 https://dev.mysql.com/doc/c-api/8.0/en/mysql-options.html